# Angular Route-based Animations: Issue with Nested Routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-animations

I'm trying to implement a slide-in/slide-out animation when the route changes. I've created a minimal reproduction of my setup here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ueeuyd

I have a 3-level hierarchy of routes: Cuisines -> Dishes -> Recipe

Each route has a module associated with it, which is lazy loaded using the `loadChildren` property in its parent route. The animations are set up to use the `depth` property that is included in the route data.

The issue is the following:
Whenever I move from a parent route to a child route, the animations of the parent route are also played. [image: Route Animation Behaviour]

Has anyone experienced this before? Any thoughts on how I can fix this?